# Xcode mixing Branches

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, macos, core-data

This may sound strange, but I am having issues with Xcode mixing branches, or at least messing everything up.

I created a new branch (v1.4), then created a new data model and renamed an entity. Had to switch back to previous branch (v1.3) to check something and I get errors at run time on v1.3, it's looking for the new entity name from Branch v1.4 - what the %$^#% is happening. I searched the files, the new entity name is nowhere in v1.3.

I switch branches again to v1.2 and it ran fine. So, switched to V1.3 again - nogo. Switched back to v1.2 and it has the same issue now, runtime error because it can't find the new entity name.

What is happening? Anyone else have this issue?

Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

OS X 10.11.6

Xcode 7.1.1

==[EDIT]===

I am not real familiar with GIT, just starting to learn. I ran the couple commands as mentioned, get nothing for either `git diff` commands.

Running `git status --ignored` I do get multiple files as untracked - still working on understanding why (Separate issue) - couple object files and 2 data models (Was 3, but manually added one to commit.

Also I get 3 ignored files:

- .DS_Store
- projectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
- projectName/.DS_Store

That's as far as I've gotten. Not familiar enough with git to know if these ignored files are the ones I should delete.

Second option - will restoring from time machine fix this? It may be a little extra work for me to recreate v1.4 but probably less time than I've already spent trying to figure out how to fix it.

I do appreciate both comments so far - thank you.

==[SECOND EDIT]==

Thanks again for your comments. 
However, do to time and schedule I perform a Time Machine backup before ElpieKay posted the last comment, so I will not be able to test it.

Reverting back did "fix" it as you'd expect, but I did lose several hours of work but life happens. I will keep this for if/when this happens again and try the `git clean -df` to see it fixes it.

On a side note - while I was switching back and forth between V1.3 and V1.4 trying to figure this out, 2 of the model versions disappeared on v1.4 - i.e. the name turned red in Xcode and when I viewed the contents of the file they were missing. I do not know if this is related or not, but I thought I would mention it. This happened one other time and I thought maybe I did something - I did a time machine restore to fix it last time. Wonder if `git clean -df` would have fixed it.

Comment: You may have some untracked files which are generated at run time. When you switch to v1.3 from v1.4, these files of v1.4 are kept. Run `git status --ignored` to find them all. If they exist, remove them. Besides, some files may be changed unexpectedly when switching branches. `git diff` or `git diff --cached` to have a check.

Comment: Git will keep changes between branches if the checkout doesn't modify the same hunk (part of a file). So you may end up with something changed, and uncommitted, coming with you to the other branch.

Comment: Thanks - Ran `git ststus` shows several untracked filed, including 3 versions on the model. Ran `git status --ignored` and shows the .ds_store and the project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/ files. Should these be removed? `git diff` and `git diff --cached` shows nothing.

Comment: Make a backup first. Then switch to v1.3 and try `git clean -df`, which removes all untracked directories and files.